# How to find occurences of a lettter in the string array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, objective-c, xcode

I'm beginner trying to implement this logic can anyone suggest the logic.

```
func findLetterOccurence(Letter: String){
    let array = ["Data", "program", "questions", "Helpful"]

    ///Logic to find the given letter occurences in string array

    print("\(Letter) occured in \(count) times")
}
```

Expected Output: a occured in 3 times

I've tried as below:

```
var count = 0
for i in array {
   var newArray.append(i)
   count = components(separatedBy: newArray).count - 1
}
```

But I don't understand what exactly the logic inside components(separatedBy:) ? I mean without higher function how can we implment logic here.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I've updated mr question pls have a look

Comment: Use `components(separatedBy:)` with each element in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ways.

```
    @discardableResult func findLetterOccurence(letter: String) -> Int {
    
    let array = ["Data", "program", "questions", "Helpful"]
    var count = 0
    // here we join the array into a single string. Then for each character we check if the lowercased version matches the string lowercased value. 
    array.joined().forEach({ if $0.lowercased() == letter.lowercased() { count += 1} } )
    
    print("\(letter) occured in \(count) times")
    
    return count
}
```

You could also do a sensitive compare and leave the casing alone
by saying

```
array.joined().forEach({ if String($0) == letter { count += 1} } )
```

Another way would be this

```
//here our argument is a character because maybe we just want to search for a single letter.
    @discardableResult func findLetterOccurence2(character: Character) -> Int {
    
        let array = ["Data", "program", "questions", "Helpful"]
   
    //again join the array into a single string. and reduce takes the `into` parameter and passes it into the closure as $0 in this case, and each element of the string gets passed in the second argument of the closure.
        let count = array.joined().reduce(into: 0) {
           $0 += $1.lowercased() == letter.lowercased() ? 1 : 0
        }
        print("\(letter) occured in \(count) times")
    
        return count
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
 func findLetterOccurence(letter: String) {
    var count = 0
    for word in array { count += word.filter{ String($0) == letter}.count }
    print("--> \(letter) occured in \(count) times")
}
```

You have to adjust if you want case insensitive, like this:

```
func findLetterOccurence(letter: String) {
    var count = 0
    for word in array { count += word.filter{ String($0).lowercased() == letter.lowercased()}.count }
    print("--> \(letter) occured in \(count) times")
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using filter too

Answer (score 0):

add this extension to find occurance of latter in string

```
extension String {
    func numberOfOccurrencesOf(string: String) -> Int {
        return self.components(separatedBy:string).count - 1
    }
}
```

use it for array

```
        func findLetterOccurence(Letter: String){
        let array = ["Data", "program", "questions", "Helpful"]
        var number = 0
        for str in array{
            var l = Letter
//            uncomment it to use code for upper case and lower case both
//            l = str.lowercased()
            
            number = number + str.numberOfOccurrencesOf(string: l)
        }
        print("\(Letter) occured in \(number) times")
    }
```